# FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to take user input with textfields and converting them into numbers so I can get their added values and display them in another container but it gives this error. At first I thought because it had no value before the textfield was used, so I tried giving it an initials text inside`TextEditingController input1 = TextEditingController(text: '0');` but nothing worked so I'm at an impass

```
TextEditingController input1 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController input2 = TextEditingController();
int inputToData = int.parse(input1.text);
int inputToData2 = int.parse(input2.text);

int addition = inputToData + inputToData2;

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("deneme")),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 280,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 40,
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: input1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 280,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: input2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 280,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text(
                addition.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seemed to work the first time I entered the codes but after restarting the app it gave this error. I also wanted it to update the added value everytime I changed the numbers sort of like a calculator. I tried using onSubmitted and setState but nothing really happened.

Comment: Why is there code outside your class? Where does that come from? That should go inside the class probably?

Comment: when they're inside the class, it says "The instance member 'input1' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"

Comment: Yes, now you are one step closer to a solution. Why do you have those calculations inside the class and not at a button press or something? Shouldn't they only be calculated upon some event?

Comment: I wanted it to calculate when any one of the textfields were edited, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Well, maybe *that* should have been the question :) Start with the examples in the documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: I followed the guide but I couldn't figure out how I will get the result in the text container below, I can't access the function.